# How to plot character matrix with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'd like to plot a character matrix in Matlab, for example this matrix

M = ['test1','test2' ; 'test3','test4'];

Is there a simple way to implement it in Matlab?

Thank you

Comment: How would you like to plot the matrix? Write the character arrays in an axis at some (which?) locations, or something else?

Comment: Something very simple, just an image corresponding to the matrix M, with each letter in a case and no axes.

Comment: Check [`text`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html). You can define a grid of coordinates and use a loop to add the letters to the figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text` command allows you to plot multiple strings at once.

With your example:

```
M = {'test1','test2';'test3','test4'};

%// adjust x-multiplicator if text becomes very long
[xx,yy] = ndgrid((0:size(M,1)-1)*2+1,1:size(M,2));

figure,
th = text(xx(:),yy(:),M(:));
%// set additional properties, such as centering text horizontally and vertically
set(th,'horizontalAlignment','center','verticalAlignment','middle');

xlim([0 max(xx(:))])
ylim([0,max(yy(:))])
```

Comment: It's very useful and simple ,thank you ! However, I wonder how to center this text on a grid ? (like in a table where  the vertical and horizontal lines are visible)

Comment: the x,y coordinates for text normally anchor the lower right corner. you can use the property/values options to center the text on the specified point. `(...,'horizontalalignment', 'center',...)`  text properties can be found at: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Text-Properties.html#Text-Properties